# Crosstalk issue on Arduino Mega 2560 Board using external supply with relay

Tags: arduino

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgJ9z2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am new to arduino. As per the forum and guide, i have connected the circuit as per attachment, by pull up resistors to control the floating of the pins But having the Cross talk/floating pins issue whenever i switch on/off any of the switch the other pin shows the float issue. Connected around 17 switches all as per the image to arduino pins from 22 to 38.

```
int prevPinVal[17];

void setup() {
 // put your setup code here, to run once:
 for(int i=22; i<=38;i++)
 {
   pinMode(i, INPUT);
   prevPinVal[i-22] = digitalRead(i);
 }
 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 int pinVal;

 for(int i=22; i<=38; i++)
 {
   pinVal = digitalRead(i);
   if(pinVal != prevPinVal[i-22])
   {
     Serial.print("<");
     Serial.print(i);
     Serial.print(",");
     Serial.print(pinVal);
     Serial.print(">");
   }
   prevPinVal[i-22] = pinVal;
 }
 Serial.println("");
 delay(1000);

}
```

Code used is as per following:[![Circuit Image][2]][2]

Comment: Your schematic is confusing.. your "pull-up" is connected to 5V+ and 5V-(GND). The naming (5V-(GND), etc) and the arrows do not help. Also, why are you connecting a relay to a switch? And you are using "digitalRead" on a relay..? Are you trying to make some kind of mux?

Comment: Schematic/block diagram does not make sense. VTC.

Comment: I agree. Please try to draw a schematic using the proper symbols for the components, and name the signals sensibly (0V/GND, +5V, etc) so we can see what is connected where. (It is possible that in carrying this out you may realise the answer to your problem anyway.)

Comment: Dear Thank you for your response.
Just to define, which GND is used where, i have marked 12v- and 5v-. Its the requirement to use the switch on 12V.
And digital read is used on pin not on relay, whenever we toggle the switch, which will make the relay to pass the 5V GND to arduino to some pin.

Comment: are you using Mega to read the status of relay? Mega is not used to switch the relay? physical switch is sued to switch the relay?

Comment: Physical switch is used to switch the relay, then the output of the relay is sent to arduino pins (22-38), to whcih i am reading through digital read on serial monitor. Relay is used here only to pass 5V GND to arduino as swtich is used on 12 V SMPS. 5V+ through resistors are sent to pins not to GND, image updated.

Comment: _”Connected around 17 switches all as per the image”_ Not shown in the picture.

Comment: How is arduino powered? Float issue means what exactly is the behaviour? if you switch smaller numbers ( 4 or 6) do you see the problem? can SMPS support 17 relays all at the same time? which relay? what is the current capability of 12 V SMPS

Comment: 17 relays are connected in parallel. Arduino is powered through USB, as i have clearly mentioned here i am reading it on computer through serial monitor of arduino IDE 1.8.2. Current capability of the SMPS is 3A. 
Exact issue is, whenever i switch on any switch or continuously multiple switches are switched on/off, some random pin will also show the change. means if i am switching 22,38,35 continuously or randomly then some time 26, some time 24 etc will show the change in pin voltage.

Comment: Perhaps a classic case for the need to "debounce" the inputs.  Google: "switch debouncing in software", add 'Arduino' to the search terms for extra points.

Comment: Are they magnetic relays and does switching one relay maybe make the neighbour bounce? As for debouncing adding a 0.1uF condensator to each pin should help too.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Dear Sir, I tried with the debounce but the issue is still there, I think, debounce is used for the same pin debouncing not for the other pins.

Comment: Whatever the issue is, it is not presented in a way that makes an answerable question within the requirements of this site.  Perhaps you should tear the whole system down, and rebuild it with only two channels to test.  If the issue persists, clearly explain and fully document the system and the problem.  If you are going to use a picture, the picture should be taken perpendicular to the drawing being photographed.  Also include a picture of the physical implementation.

Comment: Can you short the relay contacts to see if the same thing happens?

Comment: And also add flyback diodes and see if any improvement, see the updated answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can debounce the other pins to , here is an example where it needs eight successive identical readings to validate the change:

```
int prevPinVal[17];
unsigned char debounce_buffer[17];
void setup() {
 // put your setup code here, to run once:
 for(int i=22; i<=38;i++)
 {
   pinMode(i, INPUT);
   prevPinVal[i-22] = digitalRead(i);
   debounce_buffer[i-22] = 255; //Set all bits to one (inactive)
   // The initial value is not debounced but you can use
   //the same multiple readings to set the initial value
 }
 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 int pinVal;

 for(int i=22; i<=38; i++)
 {
   pinVal = digitalRead(i);
   //Shift the last reading into LSB
   debounce_buffer[i-22] = (debounce_buffer[i-22]<<1)| pinVal;
   pinVal = prevPinVal[i-22];//defaults to the old value
   // change only for eight successive identical readings 
   if (debounce_buffer[i-22]==255) pinVal = 1; 
   if (debounce_buffer[i-22]==0) pinVal = 0; 
   //Now check the value as before
   if(pinVal != prevPinVal[i-22])
   {
     Serial.print("<");
     Serial.print(i);
     Serial.print(",");
     Serial.print(pinVal);
     Serial.print(">");
   }
   prevPinVal[i-22] = pinVal;
 }
 Serial.println("");
 delay(100);// change the delay to read faster to accommodate with the multiple reading

}
```

The code can be optimized for memory size since you're using an int to store a bit. The other unused 15 bits can be used for debounce.

I didn't optimized myself to keep the code easy to understand.

**Update**

Also you should put flyback diode on the relays, the peak in the coil voltage might be the source of the noise on the unused inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnDqrs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @Hemantsalwan I don't think this is an issue. I hope you noticed that I changed the delay to 100ms so it will loop ten times faster. You cannot see a pulse shorter than 1 second anyway , so the changes are rare. Printing is very fast, Arduino uses buffer for serial , the text is going to the buffer then sent in background. The schematic is correct? Can you please check and confirm?

Comment: Contact bounce is unlikely to explain one switch changing a *different* input unless the relays are horrible or the whole system vibrating a lot.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You're right but I don't see there any diode on the relay coil so it might have high spikes that can disturb other inputs. What's strange is that the reading is made at 1 second interval , the chances to fit right at the contact time are very low.  He should try to see if shorting only the relays contact has the same efect.

Comment: Inductive kickback and contact bounce are two completely different things.  Mixing them up only confuses the situation more than it already is.  Note also that the Arduino is not driving the relay ("Physical switch is used to switch the relay, then the output of the relay is sent to arduino pins ") so there's not any apparent path of conduction for a coil turn-off spike to get into the Arduino.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What if he uses a long flat cable to the relays? I quote from his comment: " i am switching 22,38,35 continuously or randomly then some time 26, some time 24 etc will show the change in pin voltage" So sometimes it can be right at the reading moment.   What other explanation might be?

Comment: Until the poster writes a proper question, we won't know.  Answers on Stack Exchange sites should be fact based, not wild guesses confusingly intermixing extremely different subjects.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think the OP has posted all information he has tough. Giving other details not requested is beyond his knowledge. What other facts do you need ? I added a much better schematic to it's question but I see that still has a "not visible until it is peer reviewed." warning. If he is a beginner be kind and help him write a proper question and ask details that you need.

Comment: Consider that you are speculating about details of the physical implementation, rather obviously there's a lot that is missing from the question.  The poster really should simplify the project to a clean implementation with two channels and then start expanding it to figure out where the issue arrises.  It's also possible that the relays are an unnecessary complication; if they are purely to isolate inputs optoisolators would be preferable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree with optos, I would also suggest that but I think that at a question like " If I do that , why this happens?" the answer "Don't do that" it's not an answer. I think my answer to have this flaw somehow, I think the EM noise form relay coils is the most likely source.

Comment: Your "answer" is not an answer, but a guess, in denial of some realities of the circuit and assuming other things which may not even be present.  Stack exchange sites are for facts, not guesses.

Comment: Dear @Dorian Sir,

Your code was really helpful to remove the regular arising cross talk issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hemantsalwan I'm glad it did. Don't forget to mark as accepted answer if you think  that this worked for you. Whatewer your circuit does please also search google for "relay coil transient suppression" and use one otherwise other strange errors will happen.

Comment: @ChrisStratton There is not a nice way to express my opinion on your "expertise" in this field and your social skills. My "guess" is that you don't have many happy customers with this attitude. Have a nice day.

Comment: Dear @Dorian Sir, 
Further on this project, I am using a bidirectional 4Pin Encoder with this circuit, attaching Input pins to Arduino Pin 2 & 3 and Arduino's 5V Phase and ground. 
In this, now whenever some switch is toggled, it affects the value of Encoder,

Comment: @Hemantsalwan Please use a diode on the relay coil. Is there any reason you cannot modify the relay layout? You could use the same way with multiple reading but you really should eliminate the source of errors. If making modifications to the relays side is not possible than you might want to move the debounce part into a timer interrupt routine to run in background

Comment: @Hemantsalwan The encoder has much faster pulses an filtering the glitches will be less efficient. How many pulses per second du you expect from the encoder?

Answer (score 0):

pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP); // attach internal pullup resistor

Comment: This could do with some extra explaination...

Comment: It has an external pullup of 10k

Comment: Already tried both internal and external Pull ups, Butt issue remains. Currently it is with externally 10K.